# How do I find multiple non-greedy instances of a Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following text

```
var s = "{{http://foo.com:::Foo Inc.}} would like you to visit {{http://foo.com/home:::Our New Home Page}}"
```

I want to parse out both instances of the double braces using the following `Regex` and `MatchEvaluator`

```
var r = new Regex("\\{\\{(.+)\\:\\:\\:(.+)\\}\\}");

public string Convert(Match m) {
  var link = m.Groups[0].ToString();
  var text = m.Groups[1].ToString();
  return "<a href=\"" + link + "\">" + text + "</a>";
}
```

so that the output would be:

```
var output = r.Replace(s, Convert);
// output = "<a href="http://foo.com">Foo Inc.</a> would like you to visit <a href="http://foo.com/home">Our New Home Page</a>"
```

It keeps matching the whole string instead of each set of brackets. How can I get this to do non-greedy matches?

I have tried wrapping it in `()?` but that does not produce a non-greedy match

Comment: You might want to go and double check your understanding of how the non-greedy modifier works. You need to place it after something like a + or a * to say that it should match the minimum amount rather than the maximum. The `()?` is using the `?` as an optional modifier saying that what is in the brackets doesn't have to be present in your match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this non-greedy, negation based regex:

```
var r = new Regex( "\\{\\{(.+?):{3}([^}]+)\\}\\}" );
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gU2nE6/1)

Comment: this doesn't work. It matches the `:` in the url and doesn't parse correctly.